# Apache-FOP - reduce image sizes that are embedded into PDF

Tags: jpeg, image-resizing, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have lots of JPG images that should be embedded into the resulting PDF. They have quite a big resolution and are about 5-10MB each. I want to embed them into PDF as a preview and I'm using a fit-to-scale XSL-FO attribute. Images appear in PDF correctly resized, but the size of the resulting PDF is quite big, basically the sum of all image sizes. I'm curious what is the best way (possible ways) to reduce PDF size without preprocessing images in a separate step before generating PDF? (so that the PDF size is about the sum of sizes of all images if they were as small as they appear in PDF)

Many thanks!

Comment: I ended up preprocessing images and linking XSL-FO to the resized copies of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. postprocess the PDF. You can open it in Acrobat and save it using
   the 'reduce file size' option.
2. use another FO formatter. e.g. the Antennahouse formatter can
   downsample images.

Answer (score -2):

I am using Apache FOP 1.1.
As per my understanding your requirement is that,you want reduce image size.

```
<fo:external-graphic 
     src="url('image path')" 
     content-height="2cm" 
     height="2cm"  
     content-width="2cm" 
     scaling="non-uniform" >
</fo:external-graphic>
```

Here important part is **scaling** attribute.
It can have out of three value
 1.uniform     - it is by default if you are not specifying
 2.non-uniform - it will get according to content-width and content-height.
 3.inherit

For you requirement you should define scaling to non-uniform.That means it will not maintain aspect ration of image.
Thank you

you can refer
http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/fo11/e-fo_external-graphic.html

Comment: How would the 'scaling' attribute help reduce his file size? He needs downsampling, not resizing. And non-uniform scaling is asking for problems, you'd need to specify the height and width for every image or risk distorting them.

Comment: Agree with Hobbes comment, this answer is misleading as it confuses between downsampling and resizing