# reduce size of PDF generated with FOP

Tags: image, pdf, size, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have unsuccessfully browsed this site (that has so often saved my life in the past) and the web for an answer to this question:

I use Java, XSL-FO and FOP to generate PDFs that consist in one or more pages of data and images, each page having a header and a footer containing images themselves. These header and footer are repeated on each and every page of the PDF documents.
The images are responsible for a large part of the size of the resulting PDF (about 50 %). I noticed that, by converting them from JPEG to TIFF, and by reducing their resolution, I was able to reduce considerably the size of the PDF as well. But I now have the feeling that I have reached a dead-end as far as images as concerned.

The PDFs are still very huge, compared to those that used to be generated with FrameMaker, the Adobe PDF generation system that we're willing to get rid of. And I'm sorry to say that I can't think of another way to reduce the PDFs' size, as the Web mainly talks about pre-processing images in order to make PDFs smaller.
I was wondering whether, maybe, it would be possible in a way or another to tell FOP to repeat the images in all headers and footers in some kind of way so that the images would be embedded only once in the document and just "mirrored" on the other pages.
Plus, there ought to be other ways to reduce the PDF size, apart from images, don't you think?

I would highly appreciate any advice on this topic. Thanks a lot in advance for your time and help.

Erwann

Comment: If you don't find a way with XSL FO, you might consider adding repeating header and footer material in a second pass using a PDF manipulation library like itext. Such libraries can include images but once and reference them from many pages.

Comment: Are your TIFF images compressed? If your images are black and white, use Group 4 compression. If they're color, use lzw. Also, if color isn't important, you can disable the sRGB colorspace (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/configuration.html).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Sorry for the delay in my response, that was due to a problem in our Internet connection here at work.

Comment: Jeez, this is some cranky comment editor. anyway, the tiffs are indeed compressed using the LZW method. Unfortunately, group4 is not relevant in my case. I also disabled the sRGB colorspace, as you suggested, but it is only responsible for 3 or 4 KB from what I read on the subject. I'll have a go with iText and see what I can do with it.

Comment: I must also let you know than, meanwhile, I also discovered that the Adobe Acrobat Optimizer functionnality is useless BUT the "print as Adobe PDF" functionnality does the trick! With this stuff, I managed to decrease the size of my PDF from 27 MB to 2 or 3 MB. That's another solution I'm now going to try and implement in my Java app. It's a shame FOP is not more optimized though.

Comment: This seems like a question for the fop user mailing list. Or you need to supply an example.

Comment: See [this earlier post][1]: you may have to switch to another rendering engine. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786688/apache-fop-reduce-image-sizes-that-are-embedded-into-pdf/18900468#18900468